# Pumping lemma is used to show a language is non-regular /non-CFL.

Tags: context-free-grammar, finite-automata, pumping-lemma

A language L satisfies the pumping lemma for regular languages and also the pumping lemma for context free languages.Which of the following statements about L is true ?

A. L is necessarily a regular language.

B. L is necessarily a CFL but not Regular.

C. L is necessarily a non-regular.

D. None

I'll clear where I'm having doubt. If L satisfies pumping lemma for regular languages then it is not necessarily regular. Same with context free. So it can be Regular or non-regular. CFL or non-CFL. Answer given is B but in my opinion it should be D. Can anyone point out what I'm missing.

Comment: Erm.. this site isn't a way of getting people to do your homework for free you know.

Comment: This isn't my homework. I'm having doubt in this question. I know if a language satisfies pumping lemma for regular language then it is not necessary that it is regular.

Comment: "Answer given is B but in my opinion it should be B. Can anyone point out what I'm missing." - You seem to be missing that if the answer given is B and in your opinion it should be B, then nothing seems to be missing.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I edited the question. In my opinion answer should be D.

Comment: It seems this question would be better suited at http://cs.stackexchange.com/ (It also reads like a homework/exam question.)

Comment: Frankly this question lacks context (is too vague) and cannot be answered only from the info stated here. The pumping lemma(s) can be stated in various ways, most notably either as properties of a regular/CFL language or (as used in a proof by contradiction) stated as properties that imply that a language is *not* regular/CFL. The textbook/exam/whatever-this-was-copied-from probably has the prerequisite context for answering it, but this snippet doesn't.

Comment: Pumping lemma is used to show a language is non-regular. If a language satisfies pumping lemma then it may or may not be regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer B is definitely not right. Try the language Σ*, which is absolutely regular and definitely context-free. It also passes the conditions of both pumping lemmas. Therefore, it's definitely not the case that the language is context-free but not regular.

Both pumping lemmas give *necessary* conditions for a language to be regular or context-free, rather than *sufficient* conditions for those languages to be regular or context-free. Therefore, if a language passes both of the pumping lemmas, it *might* be regular and it *might* be context-free, but there's no guarantee that this must necessarily be the case.

I'm pretty sure D is the correct choice here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's not what the pummping lemmas do. They can be stated as properties of regular/CFL languages, in which case the language is both CF and regular (because those are the premises in that scenario) thus regular, or they can stated as properties that imply the language is not CF/regular, in which case the language is not CF (which includes being non-regular). But the question doesn't say which of these variants of the pumping lemma(s) it is talking about.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff I've never seen the variants of the pumping lemmas that you're referring to (the ones that say that if a language has some property, it's definitely not a CFL). Can you provide a reference to this? I'm curious to see how they work.

Comment: Any mathematical statement of the form "p implies q" can be restated as "non-q implies non-p". And that's exactly what happens with the pumping lemmas... The pumping lemmas are often used in proofs in the latter form (failure to have a R/CF- pumping property implies the language is not R/CF). However, after a brief survey, I find the first form (R/CF language has R/CF-pumping property) to be predominant in the literature *as the lemma(s) statement(s)*. [continues in the next comment due comment length limit]

Comment: Hopcroft and Ullman (all their books), Meduna's *Elements of Compiler Design* (2007) p. 56  and Linz' *An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata* (2011) p. 115 all state it like this (language is R/CF implies language has R/CF pumping property). So in that case the only meaning I can assign to the rather nonsensical OP statement "*language* satisfies the *lemma(s)*" is that the language is regular (& CF) so regular. This kind of muddy question formulation would have been immediately closed on math.SE...

Answer (score 0):

#### Hint:

1. Pumping Lemma: `¬q → ¬p` where, q is pumping lemma and p is regular language. It is `Contrapositive` that means if a language does not satisfies pumping lemma, then it can not be regular language. It is always true.
2. [Then, it is also correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Converse_of_lemma_not_true) that `p → q`. It is implication that means if a language is regular then it is always satisfies pumping lemma.

Also, note that [its inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074661/understanding-inverse-logic) `¬p → ¬q` and converse `q → p` need not be true according to prepositional logic.